# dmtracedump doesn't work, HELP!

Tags: android, profiling

I want to profiling an android app.
I follow the instructions on Android's website here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html

The website told me to use Debug.startMethodTracing() and Debug.stopMethodTracing()
Then finally I generate a trace file for my app and successfully view that file using traceview.

At the end of that web page it says there is a tool call dmtracedump can generate function call relation graph. I follow the instructions and also install Graphviz before using it.

But no matter how I try to use dmtracedump, the tool just stuck and nothing comes out.
I used commond like

dmtracedump test1.trace

dmtracedump -g test1.png test1.trace

Is there anything I got worng when using this tool?
Can any one show me how to generate a graph from dmtracedump?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You could try the dump -o option and see if that does anything

Comment: Yes I've tried -o option, it works fine.
But everything else seems broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dmtracedump is fairly broken at this point.  Only the "-o" option is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Have dmtracedump ever work fine?
Or is there any other tools that can generate Call graph on Android?

Comment: It does if you go back far enough (looks like the bad changes went in about a year ago).

Comment: Yes, I've download cupcake(android 1.5) and compile on my own.
In this version, dmtracedump works just fine.
But however, the output graph of dmtracedump seems only one thread Call relation graph.
And I can't find any option to select which thread I want.

This tool is less power than traceview

Comment: dmtracedump began life with only the "-o" flag, as a way to debug the method profiling code in the VM.  Some enterprising individuals added extra features that they wanted.  After traceview was written, dmtracedump was largely ignored.